# is complex moduli space of a Calabi - Yau Kahler

Tags: complex-geometry, calabi-yau

The complex moduli space of a Calabi-Yau manifold is a complex manifold (BTT). Is it also  Kahler ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, see
http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Calabi-Yau_manifold#Moduli_of_high_dimensional_Calabi-Yau_manifolds

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal M$ be a complex moduli space of a Calabi-Yau manifolds, then there is a symplectic metric on $\mathcal M$ which is known as Weil Petersson metric and Gang Tian showed that it is Kahler and later Georg Schomacher extended it for pair $(X,D)$ where $D$ is a divisor and proved that logarithmic Weil petersson metric on Log Fano varieties is also Kahler.

See [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510020)